# Documenting Spring @RequestMapping annotations into one location automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, documentation-generation

Javadoc is great for scanning all of source files and creating HTML pages to view it. I was wondering if there is a similar tool that would go through all of your Spring controllers and collect all of the methods that have been annotated with @RequestMapping and produce a single HTML page listing them. Sort of like a pseudo site map for developers to ensure uniqueness and standardization across controllers.

I apologize if this question has been asked elsewhere already. I could not come up with an appropriate set of search terms that would provide a useful result.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good question, I often miss (and implement) functionality like this.

### Use a Build Tool

What I'd do is run Maven (or ant) and execute a task after compilation that

- reads all classes (perhaps with a configurable list of packages)
- iterates over all methods of these classes
- reads the annotations
- and writes the output to HTML

### Use Annotation Processing

But I guess this is a scenario, where [annotation processing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html) might also be a way to do it. Usually, you have to use some internal APIs to get stuff done in API, but using [`Filer.createResource(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html#createResource%28javax.tools.JavaFileManager.Location%2C%20java.lang.CharSequence%2C%20java.lang.CharSequence%2C%20javax.lang.model.element.Element...%29) it should actually possible to do it out of the box.

Here's a rudimentary implementation:

```
public class RequestMappingProcessor extends AbstractProcessor{

    private final Map<String, String> map =
        new TreeMap<String, String>();

    private Filer filer;

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes(){
        return Collections.singleton(RequestMapping.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(
        final ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv){
        super.init(processingEnv);
        filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(
        final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        final RoundEnvironment roundEnv){

        for(final TypeElement annotatedElement : annotations){
            final RequestMapping mapping =
                annotatedElement.getAnnotation(
                    RequestMapping.class
                );
            if(mapping != null){
                addMapping(mapping, annotatedElement, roundEnv);
            }
        }
        assembleSiteMap();
        return false;
    }

    private void assembleSiteMap(){
        Writer writer = null;
        boolean threw = false;
        try{
            final FileObject fileObject =
                filer.createResource(
                    StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,
                    "html", "siteMap.html"
                );
            writer = fileObject.openWriter();
            writer.append("<body>\n");
            for(final Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
                writer
                    .append("<a href=\"")
                    .append(entry.getKey())
                    .append("\">")
                    .append("Path: ")
                    .append(entry.getKey())
                    .append(", method: ")
                    .append(entry.getValue())
                    .append("</a>\n");
            }
            writer.append("</body>\n");

        } catch(final IOException e){
            threw = true;
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } finally{

            // with commons/io: IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer)
            // with Guava: Closeables.close(writer, rethrow)
            // with plain Java this monstrosity:
            try{
                if(writer != null){
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch(final IOException e){
                if(!threw){
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            } finally{
            }
        }
    }

    private void addMapping(final RequestMapping mapping,
        final TypeElement annotatedElement,
        final RoundEnvironment roundEnv){
        final String[] values = mapping.value();
        for(final String value : values){
            map.put(
                value,
                annotatedElement.getQualifiedName().toString()
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that I know of that would do that. I've retrieved controllers and mappings via the app context before to create navigation, but it was a lot of work for little gain IMO:

```
@Component
public class SiteMap implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

  private ApplicationContext context;
  private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<Page>();

  public List<Page> getPages() {
     return pages;
  }

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
     this.context = applicationContext;
  }

  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
     Assert.notNull(context, "applicationContext not set");
     Map<String, Object> controllers = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);
     for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : controllers.entrySet()) {
        Page page = new Page();
        Class<?> controllerClass = entry.getValue();
        String controllerRoot = null;
        RequestMapping classMapping = controllerClass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        if(classMapping != null)
            controllerRoot = classMapping.value();
        if(controllerRoot = null)
            controllerRoot = // get and parse controller name
        page.setPath(controllerRoot);
        for(Method m : controllerClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            RequestMapping rm = m.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            if(rm == null)
               continue;
            Page child = new Page();
            child.setPath(rm.value());
            page.getChildren().add(child);
        }
        pages.add(page);
     }
  }

  public static class Page {
      private String path;
      private List<Page> children = new ArrayList<Page>();
      // other junk
  }

}
```

Then access `${pages}` in your site map page JSP. Might need to play with that code some if you do something similar, I freehanded it in this editor.