# Documenting your Spring MVC api?

Tags: spring-mvc, documentation

I'm looking for a tool which can document the @RequestMapping & @RequestParam annotations on a Spring MVC controller to build some kind of api which I can then give to people consuming my service. Does anyone know if such a tool is available ?

Comment: Just use normal javadoc on the controllers ? Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/4829774/106261

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9635863/106261

Comment: Sure, both viable. I was just wondering how other people build their apis ? Javadoc seems most logical of the two. If there are no other tools that people use i'll accept.

Comment: Actually, javadoc sucks pretty badly at this stuff. If I want to generate an api its reasonably unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another tool is spring-doclet

https://github.com/scottfrederick/springdoclet

It's a couple of years old but produces a nice output from your javadoc annotated files.

Comment: Aaah, very nice. I actually ended up implementing my own maven reporting plugin to do EXACTLY this. This one is nicer though.